# Show that an interpolated polynomial is unique among all polynomials of degree at most $n$

Tags: proof-verification, interpolation

For a set of $n+1$ support points $(x_i, f_i)$, show that a polynomial $P(x;a_0,\dots, a_n)$ that satisfies $P(x_i)=f_i$ is unique.

If $P(x_i)=f_i$, then

$P(x_i) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j x_i^j = f_i$   (1)

This linear equation system can be written in the matrix notation

$V \cdot \alpha = f$,                          (2)

$\alpha = (a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n)$. From there,

$\alpha = V^{-1} \cdot f$, if $V$ is invertible. We choose two polynomials $P_1(x), P_2(x)$ that satisfy (1), then

$\alpha_1 = V^{-1} \cdot f$

$\alpha_2 = V^{-1} \cdot f$

If we assume $P_2(x) \ne P_1(x)$, then

$\alpha_1 \ne \alpha_2$,

$V^{-1} \cdot f \ne V^{-1} \cdot f$

which is not true. This contradicts $P_2(x) \ne P_1(x)$, therefore $P_1(x) = P_2(x)=P(x)$.

Comment: Be careful. It is unique **among all polynomials of degree at most $n$**.

Comment: Also, why is the matrix $V$ invertible? And what is $x_{ij}^j$?

Comment: @mlainz: Is it allowed to say that if the polynomial exists, V must be invertible?

Comment: no.  Have you learnt linear algebra? That means that the linear system of equations defining $\alpha$ has a unique solution. Or that $V$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system

$$\sum_{k=0}^n p_kx_i^k=P(x_i),$$ for $i=0,\cdots n$ is linear in the $a_k$ and its matrix is of the Vandermonde form. As is well known, the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix is

$$\Delta=\prod_{0\le i<j\le n}(x_i-x_j),$$ which is nonzero when all $x$'s are different. Hence the solution of the system is unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one I have also read in the book. Is what I wrote also valid?

Comment: @tmaric: you must answer the questions in the comments. Your proof is difficult to follow and working with two polynomials is overkill.

Comment: I tried answering the questions in the comments. I understand it is an overkill to work with a linear equation system and two polynomials, I would just like to learn if it is correct or not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @tmaric: your argument requires that $V$ be invertible. A justification is missing.

Comment: Is a statement "If a polynomial exists that satisfies $1$, then $V$ must be invertible." sufficient? In your proof, you define the determinant of $V$. What I was (maybe wrongly) thinking is to state: if a polynomial exists, then it is constructed from the solution of a linear system, therefore $V$ must be invertible. Assume there are two polynomials that are different, and show this can't be because $V,f$ are the same for the both of them.

Comment: @tmaric: "therefore $V$ must be invertible" is wrong.